# How to secure webservice url in android apk file

Tags: android, web-services, security, http, post

I have built one android app, in which it gets data from web service from the url I have mentioned say, "http://www.google.com/getData"

If anyone decrypts my apk file, the webservice url will become visible and there is a chance of misusing it or can use my data or even customize it. I am using android built in HTTP POST for calling web service and getting data.

I want my webservice url to be protected from snoopers, hackers etc. Please suggest what mechanism I can use for securing my web service url. Its a burning issue to me.  I am beginner to android. Please help!

Any suggestion or help is appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: See this http://shabbirdhangot.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/secure-web-service-url-in-android/

Answer (score 3):

> Try this links i hope these links help
>
> [1]:
>   https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31024/encrypt-data-within-mobile-app-and-send-to-web-service
>
> [2]:
>   https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30850/web-services-how-prevent-illegal-accesses

Comment: The answer to the first question sums up well what is the real problem.

Comment: See this http://shabbirdhangot.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/secure-web-service-url-in-android/